# Realtime Xamarin Tesseract detection

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, ocr, tesseract

I am attempting to use tesseract in Xamarin.Forms for text character recognition on images. On Android, I've implemented the logic using the steps below;

1. Grab bitmaps of the TextureView.
2. Convert bitmaps to black and white.
3. Crop needed from the bitmap image
4. Set tesseract image with cropped image

**Currently facing memory issues and haven't got a way around it so far**

Snippets below show the main functions of the code.

```
    public async void takeContinuousPhotos(){

        byte[] newBytes;
        byte[] bytes;

        while (ocrTextChosen == false){

            bytes = await CapturePhoto();

            newBytes = this.CropPhoto(bytes, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(40, view.Height / 2 - 200, view.Width - 40, 100), (view.Width - 40) * 2, 200);

            if (!_tesseract.Initialized)
            {
                await _tesseract.Init("eng");

                var result = await _tesseract.SetImage(new MemoryStream(newBytes));

                if (result)
                {
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                        this.ocrText.Text = this._tesseract.Text;
                    }); 
                    _tesseract.Clear();
                    bytes = new byte[0];
                    newBytes = new byte[0];
                }
            }
            else {
                var result = await _tesseract.SetImage(new MemoryStream(newBytes));
                if (result)
                {
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                        this.ocrText.Text = this._tesseract.Text;
                    });
                    _tesseract.Clear();
                    bytes = new byte[0];
                    newBytes = new byte[0];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Capture photo from stream
    public async Task<byte[]> CapturePhoto()
    {
        var ratio = ((decimal)Height) / Width;

        var blackwhiteBitmap = this.toGrayscale(liveView.Bitmap);

        var image = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(blackwhiteBitmap, 0, 0, blackwhiteBitmap.Width, (int)(blackwhiteBitmap.Width * ratio));

        byte[] imageBytes = null;

        using (var imageStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            await image.CompressAsync(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 10, imageStream);
            image.Recycle();
            imageBytes = imageStream.ToArray();
            imageStream.Dispose();
        }

        image = null;
        return imageBytes;
    }
```

takeContinuousPhotos() is then run on the TextureView delegate method as shown below:

```
  public void OnSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height)
    {
        camera = Android.Hardware.Camera.Open();
        var parameters = camera.GetParameters();
        var aspect = ((decimal)height) / ((decimal)width);

        var previewSize = parameters.SupportedPreviewSizes
                                    .OrderBy(s => System.Math.Abs(s.Width / (decimal)s.Height - aspect))
                                    .First();

        parameters.SetPreviewSize(previewSize.Width, previewSize.Height);
        parameters.FocusMode = Android.Hardware.Camera.Parameters.FocusModeContinuousPicture;

        camera.SetParameters(parameters);
        camera.SetPreviewTexture(surface);
        StartCamera();

        Task.Run(() => {
            this.takeContinuousPhotos();                
        });
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a sample project somewhere? Github?